# Trying to use two separate instances of getline() to fill two separate vectors

Tags: c++, getline

I am working on [this HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-nested-logic/problem).

In my problem, I am trying to use `getline()` to enter two different lines of input into two separate vectors for organization purposes.

The input looks like this:

> 9 6 2015
>   6 6 2015

Here is my code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> expecDate;
    vector<int> retDate;
    string firstLine;
    string secLine;
    while(getline(cin, firstLine)){
        stringstream ss(firstLine);
        while(getline(ss,firstLine,' ')){
            int num = atoi(firstLine.c_str());
            retDate.push_back(num);
        }
    }
    while(getline(cin, secLine)){//want to use this second instance of getline() to fill the expecDate vector
        stringstream ss_2(secLine);
        while(getline(ss_2,secLine,' ')){
            int num_2 = atoi(secLine.c_str());
            expecDate.push_back(num_2);
        }
    }
    int year_e, month_e, day_e;
    int year_a, month_a, day_a;

    year_a = retDate[2];
    month_a = retDate[1];
    day_a = retDate[0];
    year_e = retDate[5];//want this to be expecDate[2]
    month_e = retDate[4];//want this to be expecDate[1]
    day_e = retDate[3];//want this to be expecDate[0]

    if(year_a <= year_e && month_a <= month_e && day_a <= day_e){
        cout<<"0"<<endl;
    }else if(year_a > year_e){
        cout<<"10000"<<endl;
    }else if(month_a > month_e){
        int total_m = 500*(month_a - month_e);
        cout<<total_m<<endl;
    }else if(day_a > day_e){
        int total_d = 15*(day_a - day_e);
        cout<<total_d<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This code returns the correct output, I am just curious as to how I can make it so I can use both vectors instead of `getline()` simply filling the first `vector` completely.

Update: with this code expecDate is not being filled at all. Trying to reference any of its members with cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Oh sorry I should have been more specific with that. expecDate isn't filled using the code I have now. Trying the use it throws a seg fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `while` is incorrect in your code.

```
while(getline(cin, firstLine)){
   ...
}
```

will keep on reading data from `cin` until there is nothing to read from it. After that,

```
while(getline(cin, secLine)){
   ...
}
```

does not do anything since there is nothing in `cin` to read from.

Don't use `while`. Use `if`.

```
if (getline(cin, firstLine)){
   ...
}

if (getline(cin, secLine)){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are 100 percent correct and this worked like a charm.

Comment: @IanChristner you've just earned the [vote up privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). If you found this answer helpful, feel free to upvote it as well!